# Why am I getting the error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, osx-lion, llvm, easy-install

I am setting up os X 10.7.

I am using the default install of Python:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/

I use a Python based package manager called easy_install. 
Easy_install seems to not be able to find the compiler.

EDIT: When I tried to install  MySQL-python I got this error:

```
$ sudo easy_install MySQL-python 
Password:
Searching for MySQL-python
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/MySQL-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.3
Downloading http://download.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/mysql-python/MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz
Running MySQL-python-1.2.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-P9H9WX/MySQL-python-1.2.3/egg-dist-tmp-rRTfZL
warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
unable to execute llvm-gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

Xcode 4.1 used GCC, but with Xcode 4.2 that seems to have changed.

What compiler does Apple want us to use?
How do I setup the configuration so I can compile OSS?

Comment: What package are you trying to use easy_install to install?

Comment: The command "failed", it's not a "not found". Show us more context / log to understand your issue.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried with Xcode and GCC solution! What is the solution? I need it please!

Answer (score 34):

I had the exact same problem when I upgraded from OSX 10.6 to 10.7. If you upgrade to 10.7 from 10.6, your version of Python may go from 2.6 to 2.7 and a result you may need to re-install most of your python packages.

Here's what worked for me:

1. Install the latest version of XCode from the App Store
2. Inside XCode, go to Preferences -> Downloads -> Components
3. download the **Command Line Tools**

That's all you need to do.  Try to install again in a new shell.  The command line tool installation will put llvm-gcc-4.2 into /usr/bin which should be in your default path.  The installation also takes care of library paths and stuff that you don't really want to know about unless something breaks.

**10.9 edit**

If you're running 10.9 or higher, I think you might be able to run this from the command line instead to install the command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I haven't verified that this is an actual fix to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to installing Xcode, install GCC and related tools via:

https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you ran into [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue13241).  The thread shows a variety of solutions.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is quite simple. Check out the following blogpost.
http://waqasshabbir.tumblr.com/post/19073648382/llvm-gcc-4-2-exe-error-on-mac-osx-lion-when-building

Answer (score 0):

Using OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

I tried the XCode solution, but my gevent pip installation still wasn't successful. Then, I tried building libevent from source but still no success with gevent installation. However, after I did

```
    brew install libevent
```

I was able to successfully install gevent with

```
    sudo pip install gevent
```

(Note: greenlet is also a dependency for gevent, so you may try installing it with pip as well. It was already installed on my machine.)

Answer (score 0):

All of the suggestions here (Xcode command line options, and Kenneth Reitz' stuff) didn't work for me (I am on Mac OS X 10.7.5, Xcode 4.6.3).

What helped in the end  was altering the cflags options in the mysql_config file (There were errors about 'unreconized command line options' while trying to 'sudo pip install MySQL-python').

See this post: [cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-null-conversion" within installing python-mysql on mac 10.7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127493/cc1-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-wno-null-conversion-within-insta/18825031#18825031)