# cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-null-conversion" within installing python-mysql on mac 10.7.5

Tags: python, mysql, macos, python-2.7, mysql-python

This error broke my python-mysql installation on Mac 10.7.5. Here are the steps

1. The installed python is 2.7.1, mysql is 64 bit for 5.6.11.
2. The being installed python-mysql is 1.2.4, also tried 1.2.3
3. Configurations for the installation

   ```
   1) sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib /usr/local/mysql/lib/mysql
   2) Edit the setup_posix.py and change the following mysql_config.path = "mysql_config" to mysql_config.path = "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config" 
   3) sudo python setup.py build
   ```

Here is the stacktrace for build

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
llvm-gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,4,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.4 -I/usr/local/mysql/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -Wno-null-conversion -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-null-conversion"
error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

Welcome your suggestions and ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try to Remove `cflags -Wno-null-conversion -Wno-unused-private-field` in

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config.
```

like:

```
cflags="-I$pkgincludedir  -Wall   -Os -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DDBUG_OFF -arch x86_64 " #note: end space!
```

Comment: Removed them, the installation succeeds.  A new error thrown, “Python mysqldb: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib”    resolved with this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib

Comment: This solved my problem as well trying to get mysql2 gem installed. I looked in gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql/mkmf.log and found the same error. Removing -Wno-null-conversion and -Wno-unused-private-field made it work w/o issues. Now I just wish I knew what they did...  Also, since I used homebrew to install mysql, my mysql_config was in: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.12/bin/mysql_config

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I've been spending a couple of hours on thistrying to 'pip install MySQL-python'. I have been re-installing Xcode 4.6.3, the Xcode command line tools seperatly (on Mac OS X 10.7.5), and installing Kenneth Reitz' stuff (https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) to no avail while I was ...

Altering the cflags options finally helped!

Thanks!