# Bundle install fails. Not able to install mysql2 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zsh, zshrc

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2. I dont know what I did for this to happen and I'm struggling to figure what the issue is.

Basically all most of my rails commands are failing. I'm using zsh.

When I try to run `bundle install`, I get

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150903-44386-11qoex1.rb extconf.rb --with-mysql-config=usr/local/bin/mysql_config/
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Cannot find mysql_config at usr/local/bin/mysql_config/
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/name/workspace/application/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.20 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/name/workspace/application/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.20), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I did,

`gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20'`

It suceeded.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.20
Parsing documentation for mysql2-0.3.20
Done installing documentation for mysql2 after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Now when I do a `bundle install`, it gives me the same error again.

So I tried `which mysql2`, it says `mysql2 not found`

Per this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/16132663/5245746, I checked my cflags, it looks good to me. Here is mine,

`cflags="-I$pkgincludedir   -O3 -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DDBUG_OFF " #note: end space!`

I checked the mkmf.log file. Here's the log http://pastebin.com/aZ8ySXd8

I have spent half a day on this and its really frustrating.I fell this is not an issue with mysql2, there is a bigger issue behind this. Can anyone show me some direction ? Do you guys know why this is happening.?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of RubyGems are you using? Go to your console and run `gem -v`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, mysql2's extconf is provided the option:

```
--with-mysql-config=usr/local/bin/mysql_config/
```

It should probably be (note placement of the forward slash):

```
--with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config
```

Or just not set at all, because `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config` is one of the defaults that mysql2 searches.

Comment: Yeah, when I do `which mysql_config`, it gives me `/usr/local/bin/mysql_config`. Any idea how to fix that?